# Movie with the Sun getting too strong (due to depleted ozone?), where the main character is immune because of genetic experiment by his parents

Tags: story-identification, movie

I want to say I saw this in the mid 90's, I believe it's likely from the 90's or late 80's.

The ozone layer had become so depleted or Sun became too strong such that it would cause horrific burns, even death due to exposure. The main character was at one point, roughed up by the school bullies and left outside in the sun to suffer severe burns; he's able to free himself and tells his teacher why he's late, but they teacher doesn't believe him because it's impossible for him to be unscathed if true.

The main character is fine because his parents, a geneticist and botanist have tinkered with his genes.

Comment: Similar question on another stack; [Identify this sci-fi movie in which a scientist and his family move into a new house](http://movies.stackexchange.com/q/26486)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is the straight-to-video film [**Habitat**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Habitat_(film)) from 1997.

> In a future where the Earth's ozone layer is severely decreased in
>   size, the Symes family is on the run from the father's former
>   employers and the government. Hank Symes (Tchéky Karyo) a molecular
>   biologist, has become so obsessed with saving the world that he has
>   placed his entire family's lives in danger. They stop in a desert
>   community to hide out and continue work when a terrible accident
>   occurs that transforms Hank into a fantastic ethereal lifeform and
>   begins changing the house into a huge botanical biosphere entity which
>   has the ability to threaten all who enter.
>
> Their son Andreas (Balthazar Getty), however, is experiencing things
>   from a teenager's point of view and doesn't know how he will be able
>   to attend the local school, let alone fit in with any of the local
>   kids as they all see him as some weirdo that just wandered into town.
>   No matter what Andreas feels, his father is still around him, changing
>   things for him and others and eventually even Andreas will come to see
>   that in this strange time he is living that miracles still can happen.

Comment: YES! That wire brush in the shower. That's definitely the movie. Thank you.